# Slow process to update 14 million rows

Tags: c#, list, performance, linq

I need to update the values and location/other information for 14 million records. I have the 14 million records in `interval_list`. Each iteration I use the `MeterID` from the `Interval` object to get the correct location and multiplier. I than update the location and update the value based on the multiplier. This code takes 4+ hours to run. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

```
foreach (Interval interval in interval_list)
{       
    var result = from m in meterList
                 where m.MeterID.Equals(interval.MeterID)
                 where m.StartDate < (interval.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime())
                 where m.FinalDate > (interval.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime())
                 select m;

    if (result.Count() == 1) //Ignore if > 1
    {
        int mult1 = result.ElementAt(0).Mult1;
        int mult2 = result.ElementAt(0).Mult2;
        interval.ServiceID = result.ElementAt(0).Locserv;
                                       
        // With updating check to see if value is already adjusted by mult

        if (interval.Mult1 > 1)
        {
            interval.Value = interval.Value / interval.Mult1;
            interval.Value = interval.Value * mult1;
        }

        interval.Mult1 = mult1; //MULT1
        interval.Mult2 = mult2; //MULT2
    }
}

public class Interval
{
    public string MeterID { get; set; }
    public DateTime UTCDateTime { get; set; }
    public float Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime LocalDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
    public int Mult1 { get; set; }
    public int Mult2 { get; set; }
}

public class Meters
    {
        public string MeterID { get; set; }
        public string Locserv { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime FinalDate { get; set; }
        public int Mult1 { get; set; }
        public int Mult2 { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: What is `meterList` and how large is it? I could see that query being troublesome if it's huge.

Comment: Not enough information to give a proper answer.  The important question is "How big is meterList. Count() will have to evaluate ALL items in meterList. And the second question is how often are result.Count() zero, one or more than one. I have code that does a foreach on 1 million records and that takes 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Is meterList or interval_list a linq query? It could be more efficient to use `.ToList()` before iterating over it. Could you provide more information about the 2 lists?

Comment: Are you using some kind of database or is this in-memory objects only?

Comment: I've added the Meter class to the code. It's about 22,000 records. I pull the meterlist info from a sql table into List<Meter>, so I believe it in-memory.   Interval list is List<Interval> and I populate it through a csv file. It takes me a minute to insert all 14 millions rows into the Interval list. I've noticed that just checking the result.Count() takes time. I'll take a look and see how many times result.Count() is zero.

Comment: Did you attach a profiler to your code?

Comment: It is related to ORM like EF Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at what you can do with this linq select:

```
    var result = from m in meterList
             where m.MeterID.Equals(interval.MeterID)
             where m.StartDate < (interval.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime())
             where m.FinalDate > (interval.UTCDateTime.ToLocalTime())
             select m;
```

As I said before the `result.Count()` will check ALL items in meterList.
That means that each `Count()` checks 22,000 items (with three where checks for each) and this is done 14 million times. Which totals in each item in `meterList` is checked **308,000,000,000 times**.
And there are also three `where` in that linq query, why not just use `&&`? I don't know much about the internals of linq queries, but if that is not optimized away internally it looks like it creates three state machines that handles the query.

I would have a look at optimizing `meterList`.
Before the 14 million loop, I would turn it into a `Dictionary<MeterId, List<MeterItem>>`. That way you will only get the items for that MeterId almost instantly. And also the list to check for `StartDate`/`EndDate` are reduced.

If the intersection of `MeterId` in `meterList` and `interval_list` is significantly smaller than the full lists, you could filter the lists to only contain the MeterIds that will make a hit in the result. But I do not think that will make such a big difference compared to the idea above.

Also the `Count()` should not keep counting if it finds more than one record. That could make a big difference depending on what the data looks like.

But without knowing more about what the data looks like, there is a risk that none of these ideas helps much at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. Using the Dictionary<MeterId, List<MeterItem>> method, I went from 4 hours to 2 minutes.

Comment: @BL18 Thank you for the feedback! So it is like 12000% faster now. Not bad -- not bad at all... =)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ/Entity Framework is very poor at bulk operations. You would be much better off using a bare SQL query to do this.

Guessing from your existing code, it might look like this

```sql
UPDATE il
SET
-- alternatively use SELECT
    ServiceID = m.Locserv,
    Value = CASE WHEN i.Mult1 > 1
        THEN (i.Value / i.Mult1) * m.Mult1
        ELSE i.Value
        END
    Mult1 = m.Mult1,
    Mult2 = m.Mult2
FROM interval_list i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      Mult1 = MIN(m.Mult1),
      Mult2 = MIN(m.Mult2),
      Locserv = MIN(m.Locserv)
    FROM meterList m
    WHERE m.MeterID = i.MeterID
      AND m.StartDate < GETDATE()
      AND m.FinalDate > GETDATE()
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) m;
```